# QML module not found (QtGStreamer)

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, gstreamer, qtgstreamer

I have been trying to install gstreamer on my ubuntu 18.04 and to integrate it into a Qt 5.14.1 project. (Quick heads-up: I am not a pro in things Qt and Linux.)

These are the installation steps I followed in order to install gstreamer:

```
git clone git://anongit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/qt-gstreamer
cd qt-gstreamer
mkdir build && cd build
cmake QtGstreamer
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR=lib/$(dpkg-architecture -qDEB_HOST_MULTIARCH) -DCMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR=include -DQT_VERSION=5 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-std=c++11
make -j6 && sudo make install
```

Which installed a bunch of files under */usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/* and */usr/include/Qt5GStreamer/*.

I extended the PKGCONFIG in the .pro file like so:

```
PKGCONFIG += gstreamer-1.0 gstreamer-app-1.0 gstreamer-video-1.0
PKGCONFIG += Qt5GLib-2.0 Qt5GStreamer-1.0 Qt5GStreamerQuick-1.0 Qt5GStreamerUtils-1.0
```

In my QML file I try to import it like so:

```
import QtGStreamer 1.0
```

Which results in an error.

> QML module not found. (QtGSteamer)

I would really appreciate on this matter.

Comment: How did you install Qt 5.14.1?

Comment: I used the online installer and installed it under /home/kalumo/Qt.
System Information:
Qt 5.14.1 (x86_64-little_endian-lp64 shared (dynamic) release build; by GCC 5.3.1 20160406 (Red Hat 5.3.1-6)) on "xcb" 
OS: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS [linux version 5.3.0-40-generic]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the module is not found in mldule search path. Did you update pro file as described in [Build system integration|qmake](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/qt-gstreamer/html/build_system_integration.html)?
Did you check if this module exists on file system?

Comment: I did add the lines:
CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG += QtGStreamer-1.0
to my pro file.

This did not solve it unfortunately, even with the added line:
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/Qt5GStreamer

I ended up puttung the module into the project directory and it can be found there. For now this is my working solution, though not very elegant...